# Update a multi level document in NOSQL

Tags: nosql, total.js

Iam using nosql in totajs4 .
Document structure in nosql database

{directoryName:{fileName:{"created": timestamp,"modified":timestamp,"deleted":timestamp}}}
unable to update this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing nested objects isn't supported yet in Total.js 4. I recommend reading the specific document and modify only the nested property/key.